# RMarkdown missing images

Tags: html, r-markdown

Im using an html command like this in my RMarkdown:

```
<center> <img src="C:/Users/js/Documents/r_directory_2/my_image.PNG"> </center>
```

And when I render the file to HTML, things get weird. If I open the HTML in my directory the images are shown, but if I move the HTML file to another location, the images are missing.

On the other hand, R plots are shown in both instances.

I havent had a problem like this while rendering on R Server Studio.

Any clues?

Comment: You could try `file://C:/Users/js/...`

Comment: Yes. It does work. Thanks Martin.